# Incomplete System.Collections.Generic in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010, generic-collections

I'm trying to access System.Collections.Generic.Stack<> in Visual C# 2010 Express, but the IDE (and compiler) claim that it's not present. Several other classes are also missing, including LinkedList<>, SortedList<> and Queue<>. I've checked the documentation for both the System.Collections.Generic namespace and C# Express, and can find no reference to any deliberate limitations.

Oddly enough, if I sort the documented contents of the System.Collections.Generic namespace alphabetically, everything after List<> is missing, but that may just be a very weird coincidence.

Edit:
I tried a commandline build using MSBuild, which also complained with error CS0246. However, using csc worked.

Followup:
I tried removing all resources from my project and adding a stub class which just created an instance of Stack<>. Not only did that work, everything still worked after adding the old class back in and removing the stub. I can only assume there was some kind of caching silliness going on. Very annoying. I'll re-open if this issue reappears.

Comment: Are you sure you have the relevant references added to your project? They should be there by default but may have been removed by mistake. mscorlib.dll is what you need

Comment: @Tom - If he didn't have mscorlib, then he wouldn't have List<T> and Stack<T> is in [System.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) :-)

Comment: Ah, true. Just grasping at straws here

Comment: Does the compiler give you errors, or just the IDE?

Comment: It does sound like he might be missing a reference to System.dll, since everything that's alphabetically after `List<T>` is in System.dll (whereas `List<T>` itself is in mscorlib.dll).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that your project is missing a reference to System.dll.

Check whether "System" is listed under "References" in the solution explorer. If not, right-click References, choose "Add Reference...", and add a reference to "System".

Note: `List<T>` is in mscorlib.dll, and all collections that are alphabetically after `List<T>` are in System.dll, which is why I think this is what's happening.